# Google maps performance with 2000 markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have am displaying 2000 markers on google maps. I notice the performance is a little slow. What I am not sure about... is it it slow because if the number of markers added to the map or visibility? How do I improve the performance? Can I just add them to the map and "hide" markers outside of bounds? Would that help or would it not because even though its not visible, its added to the map? The data to show the markers is in an list called `var datapoints = [...]`.

My code to add markers is like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: data.title
    });
    (function (marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    })(marker, data);
}
```

Any optimization recommendations appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options here. Google's [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=en) suggest either limiting visible markers to the current viewport, clustering (distance or grid based), or fusion tables. I've implemented google maps with a customization of the [MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) module that works quite well for large amounts of markers on one map. Best of luck!

Comment: So your saying markers added to the map, but "setVisible(false)" (not removed from the map, just visibly hidden) will help with performance?

Comment: I believe so. In my app, however, I keep a collection of markers and use the setMap() method to add or remove them from the map as the viewport changes.

Comment: @chukkwagon I have just used `setMap()` to great success, thank you